# Function to count how many numbers are there with the digits and division value specified

Tags: javascript

I started making a function that will be able do the following: *Count how many 6 digit numbers you can make with the digits 0,1,2,3,4 and 5, that can be divided by 6?*

How I currently try to start, is I make an array of all the possible numbers, then take out every number that has any of the `numbers`' arrays elements in it, then remove the ones that are not dividable with 6.

I got stuck at the second part. I tried making 2 loops to loop in the array of `numbers`, then inside that loop, create an other one for the length of the `allnumbers` array to remove all matches.

Then I would use the `%` operator the same way to get every element out that doesn't return 0.

The code needs to be flexible. If the user asks for eg. digit 6 too, then the code should still work. Any way I could finish this?

My Code is:

```
var allnumbers = [],j;
var biggestnumber = "999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999";

function howmanynumbers(digits,numbers,divideWith){
    if (digits && numbers && divideWith){
        for (var i = 0; i < 1+Number(biggestnumber.substring(0,digits)); i++ ){
            allnumbers.push(i);
        }

        for (j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++ ){
            var matchit = new RegExp(numbers[j]);
        }
            //not expected to work, I just had this in for reference
        if ( String(allnumbers[i]).match(matchit) != [""]){
            j = 0;
            allnumbers.splice(i,1);
            var matchit = new RegExp(numbers[j])
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Comment: Sounds like homework. You should probably finish it yourself.

Comment: @theTinMan Nah, a challenge from one of my friends.

Comment: anyway i'm curious what the answer is ...

Comment: Given that we are talking about six-digit numbers only containing `0,1,2,3,4,5`, the biggest possible number would be `555555`.

Comment: This isn't a javascript question but more about algorithm design.

Comment: That actually would be a very good idea to make the `biggestnumber` be the last element in the array, joined multiple times. the array will be controlled by a form, so I will always know the last is the biggest.
@ChrisMoutray But it's javascript related, and I found no better tags.

Comment: How is that title going to help anyone in the future?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my take on the entire solution:

```
var i;
var allowedDigitsPattern = /^[0-5]+$/i;
var numbers = [];

for (i = 100000; i < 555555; i++) {
    if (allowedDigitsPattern.test(i.toString())
        && i % 6 === 0) {
        numbers.push(i);       
    }
}
```

And you can look at your results like this:

```
document.write('There are ' + numbers.length + ' numbers<br>');

// write out the first ten!
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.write(numbers[i] + '<br>');
}
```

**Update based on comments...**

The configurable version of this would be:

```
var i;
var lowestDigit = 0;
var highestDigit = 5;
var numberOfDigits = 6;

var allowedDigitsPattern = new RegExp('^[' + lowestDigit + '-' + highestDigit + ']+$', 'gi');

var smallestNumber = '1';
for (i = 1; i < numberOfDigits; i++) {
    smallestNumber += '0';
}

var biggestNumber = '';
for (i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++) {
    biggestNumber += highestDigit.toString();
}

var numbers = [];

for (i = smallestNumber; i < biggestNumber; i++) {
    if (allowedDigitsPattern.test(i.toString())
        && i % 6 === 0) {
        numbers.push(i);        
    }
}

document.write('There are ' + numbers.length + ' numbers<br>');
```

You need to change the smallest and largest numbers based on the configuration. I have made both the allowable digits and the length of the number configurable.

Comment: Your code is missing the validation of the `numbers` array too. If you add that, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: I'm validating the numbers before I allow them to be added to the array - so if it isn't just digits `0,1,2,3,4,5` OR isn't divisible by 6, it doesn't get added.

Comment: But the array can contain any digits from 0-9, and the ones that are not in the array cannot be in any of the numbers.

Comment: It may not have been mentioned, but the code needs to be flexible. If the user asks for digit 6 too, then this won't work.

Comment: You could use whatever the user enters to construct that regex: `var lowestDigit = 0;
var highestDigit = 5;

var allowedDigitsPattern = new RegExp('^[' + lowestDigit + '-' + highestDigit + ']+$', 'gi');`

Comment: Here is the ultra-configurable version. Number of digits and allowed digits. http://jsfiddle.net/MhA3q/

Comment: Interesting how your code returns "6480", and SamuelCaillerie's "7776", now I don't know which one to believe.

Comment: I believe the correct answer is 6480 if you include only 6 digit numbers. The answer would be 7776 if you include number *up to* six digits (i.e. 6, 12, 24 and so on).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21479/discussion-between-steve-fenton-and-djdavid98)

Comment: @SteveFenton : I don't agree with your pattern : if digits are not consecutive, it does not work...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie you can set up the regex however you like - you could accept user input of '68423' and run that straight into the dynamic regex `allowedDigitsPattern` and that works too.